# Ribbon and stars - How to get this done without an image file?

Tags: html, css

I need to create this ribbon and stars look (image attached) without an image file.  I know how to put the stars in it, but am needing the ribbon sides like the image is attached.  How can I do this without an image file, and just pure CSS and HTML?  Am thinking that the border-radius will need to be manipulated here.

[image: Just need the Red Ribbon image!]

[This is what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/k8waC/), which is terrible.

How can I use `border-radius` to get this effect?

Comment: Google CSS triangles.

Comment: ...or http://www.css3shapes.com/

Comment: [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend combining CSS triangles with pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` for the side triangles of the ribbon, and html character ★ for the stars:

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a498M/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<h1>&#9733; KRISTINE COADY &#9733;</h1> <!-- &#9733; is html star character -->
```

**CSS:**

```css
h1{ /* all regular attributes here */
    background:#A52927;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 30px;
    color:#EEE4D3;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}

h1:before{ /* this will create white triangle on the left side */
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid white; 
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

h1:after{ /* this will create white triangle on the right side */
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0px;
    left:auto;
    right:0px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid white; 
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; 
}
```

This way you will not have to use wrappers or border-radius.. You should ofcourse alter the font, font size, height, (etc.) to your needs..

Comment: @SolomonClosson not a problem. very glad to help :)